# Filter events by date using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to filter my events by date using AngularJS and jQuery Datepicker. But it seems not working using the input text...

My code below works with the title of the event...

Main issue : when I choose a date in the jQuery Datepicker, I get no events...

```js
    $scope.onChange = function(){
      $scope.search.start = new Date(moment($scope.search.start, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00"));
      $scope.search = _.reduce($scope.search, function(result, n, key) {
        if (n !== '') {
          result[key] = n;
        }
        return result;
      }, {});
      $scope.events = data.events;
      $scope.filteredEvents = $filter('filter')($scope.events, $scope.search);
    };
```

```html
<input class="form-control datepicker" id="start" type="text" ng-model="search.start" ng-change="onChange()" autocomplete="off">
<input class="form-control" id="title" type="text" ng-model="search.title" ng-change="onChange()" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="col-12" ng-repeat="event in events | filter:search | limitTo:limit">
      <div class="event">
        <div class="event-body">
          <a href="/event/show/{{event.id}}" class="event-title">{{event.title}}</a>
          <p ng-if="event.end" class="event-date">{{event.start | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="space10"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the Box the *JQueryUI* datepicker will not work with angular because the angular model is not being updated when Jquery sets the input value.  You need to tell *JQueryUI* datepicker to update the model.

The best way to do that is create a directive that sets up the datepicker and adds an `onSelect` method that sets the view value model controllers view value `ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue` and applies it to the scope `scope.$apply()`

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="date" datepicker />
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function(){
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat:'dd/mm/y',
                    onSelect:function (date) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

If you also want to use a date in a different format than available using the Date Picker you will need to format using the `ng-change` directive.

```
 <input class="form-control " datepicker type="text" 
        ng-model="search.start" ng-change="onChange()"/>


   $scope.onChange = function(){
      $scope.search.start = moment($scope.search.start, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                            .format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000[Z]");
    };
```

[**Working Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKhq2AwTv5b8yZoUONqB?p=preview)

Comment: @tonymx227 Sorry, I realize my syntax was wrong for the year format.  I updated my answer and have a working example including the filter for you to look at.

Comment: When I get all my events from my database my dates are formatted like this `2016-02-12 00:00:00` (datetime). So it doesn't work with your code.

Comment: Sorry my date are formatted like this : `2015-11-25T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: @tonymx227 Date Picker does not support that format. I added an `ng-change` directive that will reformat on save.  See Working Example